# Merge n Google spreadsheets files to n sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Say, I have 100 google spreadsheets file and I need to merge into one file with 100 tabs(sheets). Is it possible with app script. Currently I have a code below,

```
function popForm() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for(var b = 0; b<100; b++){
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet '+b);
  var numberRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
....
....
```

The above code will work with spreadsheets with 100 tabs(Sheets). But I have 100 sreadsheets with one tab(Sheet).

Comment: where and how you define the 100 spreadsheets? are they under the same folder? are they randomly located within your google drive?

Comment: How to know which 100 spread sheets you want to process? Do you have the list of ID stored in a list in a sheet?  Or can you store the 100 spreadsheets in a single folder?  If you do, it is possible.

Comment: The above code is a sample. That is only applicable if I can join my 100 files into one file. @Marios 100 files located randomly in google drive, but with in alphabetcal order like `file1`, `file2`, `file3` etc. And that files are in one folder

Comment: Sorry, in above comment I said randomly. It is not random, it is in a specific folder.

Comment: @JustineChacko and each spreadsheet file has one sheet only? Please edit your question because other people won't read the comments and the new information you are providing won't be seen.

Comment: Please wait, I will test it and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You have a folder with `FolderId` that contains all the spreadsheet
  files. You find this folder using the [getFolderById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid) method.
- You get the files of this folder using the [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfiles) method and
  you use a while loop to iterate over these files.
- For every file, you get the first sheet and you copy it using the
  [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) method to the source (active) spreadsheet file.
- The newly create sheet will be named after the name of the spreadsheet file that it came from. Feel free to change this part or let me know so I can modify it.

---

### Solution:

You must be looking for this:

```
function myFunction() {

const source_sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderId');
const files = folder.getFiles();
  
while (files.hasNext()) { 
    var file = files.next();    
    var target_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()); 
    var target_sh = target_ss.getSheets()[0];
    target_sh.copyTo(source_sh).setName(file.getName());
    }
}
```